# how to get a new JSON response without closing and reloading the app

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, alamofire

I just started building an app that uses a REST api, I am testing the JSON response in the console.

I have 2 UITextFields `jobKeyword` & `location` that the user enter, then the JSON shows up in the console upon clicking the "search" button.

But I can't get a new search without closing a re-running the app. How do update my field and get a new response without leaving the app? I'm fairly new in iOS development. here is the ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let headers = ["Host":"data.usajobs.gov",
               "User-Agent":"dezbill@icloud.com",
               "Authorization-Key":"********************"
             ]

@IBOutlet weak var jobKeywordTxt: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var locationTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var locationState: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

}


@IBAction func searchBtn(sender: UIButton) {

    let jobKeyword = jobKeywordTxt.text
    let location = locationTxt.text

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://data.usajobs.gov/api/Search", parameters:["LocationName":location!,"PositionTitle":jobKeyword!]).responseJSON { response in
          debugPrint(response)
          print(self.locationTxt.text)
    }
}
```

}

[screenshot of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRIJR.png)

Comment: what happens when you click for second search? Code looks to be ok.

Comment: I am not sure if you are talking about async functions, to request and update in background or if its a problem in getting the JSON.

Comment: say for example: I enter "software" in the  jobKeyword text field and "Miami, Florida" in the location text field. I get JSON response in the console when I click Search. Now if I clear the fields and enter new values for each field ("nurse" and "Dallas, Texas" for example) and click the search but button again, NOTHING HAPPENS!

Comment: Hi,

First let's get this clarified whether your function "searchBtn" gets fired each time you click. Simple put a log and see whether the log gets printed each time you press the button. Then we can resolve the issue. Use this line of code below :)

print("Function called")

Comment: @Ruchira, did that already, logged the city name in the console each time the button is pressed print(self.locationTxt.text). if you are interested in solving the issue send me your email I'll add you to the repo

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code and see whether it works.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://data.usajobs.gov/api/Search", parameters:["LocationName":location!,"PositionTitle":jobKeyword!])
     .response { request, response, data, error in
         print(request)
         print(response)
         print(data)
         print(error)
      }
```

If it still doesn't work, then try installing Charles(Http debugger) and route your network traffic via Charles. Then you'll be able to at least identify whether a request is sent each time.